# Trapezoidal Integration of nonlinear inductance

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, non-linear

I have modeled the nonlinear inductor with Modelica, but the circuit can not be solved by trapezoidal integration, It is appreciated someone can help me to solve the circuit.

```
model NonlinearInductor
  import Modelica.SIunits.MagneticFlux;
  extends Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.OnePort;

  parameter Real T[:,2]=[-1.0015,-1200;-0.0015,-200;0,0;0.0015,200;1.0015,1200]
                                                                               "piecewiselinear current versus flux relation";
  Integer nbPoints = size(T,1) "Number of interpolation points";
  Real L;  //Slop of line flux-Current; inductance
  MagneticFlux flux( start=0);

equation
  v =  der(flux);     // Faraday's Low

algorithm
                // Definition of Piecewise nonlinear inductance


if  i < T[2,1] then
   L     := ((T[1,2] - T[2,2]) / (T[1,1] - T[2,1]));
   flux  :=  L  *  (i-T[1,1]) +  T[1,2];

  elseif i >= T[nbPoints-1,1] then
   L     := (( T[nbPoints-1,2] - T[nbPoints,2]) / (T[nbPoints-1,1] - T[nbPoints,1]));
   flux  := L * (i-T[nbPoints-1,1]) +  T[nbPoints-1,2];

  else
      for iter in 2:(nbPoints-2) loop
         if i >= T[iter,1] and i <T[iter+1,1] then
            L      := (( T[iter,2] - T[iter+1,2]) / (T[iter,1] - T[iter+1,1]));
            flux   := L * (i-T[iter,1]) +  T[iter,2];
         end if;
      end for;
 end if;
end NonlinearInductor;
```

and I have prepared and example as below:

```
model NonlinearInductorTest
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.CosineVoltage cosineVoltage1(V = 25e3 * sqrt(2), freqHz = 50,
    phase=1.5707963267949)                                                                                          annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-80, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor resistor1(R = 1000e6)  annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-14, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground1 annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-80, -12}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Capacitor capacitor1(C=0.4e-9)    annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 42}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  NonlinearInductor L annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {28, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
equation
  connect(L.n, ground1.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{28, 10}, {28, 10}, {28, -2}, {-80, -2}, {-80, -2}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(L.p, capacitor1.n) annotation(
    Line(points = {{28, 30}, {28, 30}, {28, 42}, {-40, 42}, {-40, 42}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(capacitor1.p, cosineVoltage1.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-60, 42}, {-80, 42}, {-80, 30}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(capacitor1.n, resistor1.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-40, 42}, {-14, 42}, {-14, 30}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(resistor1.n, ground1.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-14, 10}, {-14, -2}, {-80, -2}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(ground1.p, cosineVoltage1.n) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-80, -2}, {-80, 10}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  annotation (
    uses(Modelica(version="3.2.2")),
    experiment(StartTime = 0, StopTime = 0.1, Tolerance = 1e-6, Interval = 2e-05));
end NonlinearInductorTest;
```

Please run the example by solver Trapezoidal, StopTime = 0.1, Interval = 2e-05

Comment: Pretty difficult without having the model...

Comment: We will be better able to help you if you post a minimal working example of what you want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added the model and one example to my question. please take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Your model can be drastically simplified by using the interpolate function of the MSL. 
As far as I understood, your code does the same as this function: using linear interpolation inside the defined interval and linear extrapolation outside.

Here is the updated code:

```
model NonlinearInductor2
  extends Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.OnePort;

  parameter Real T[:,2]=[-1.0015,-1200;
                         -0.0015,-200;
                               0,0;
                          0.0015,200;
                          1.0015,1200] "piecewiselinear current versus flux relation";

  Modelica.SIunits.MagneticFlux flux( start=0);

protected 
  final parameter Real[:] i_vec = T[:, 1];
  final parameter Real[:] flux_vec = T[:, 2];

equation 
  v = der(flux);     // Faraday's Law
  flux = Modelica.Math.Vectors.interpolate(i_vec,flux_vec,i);
end NonlinearInductor2;
```

Apart from making your model much simpler to understand, the usage of the interpolate function brings also these benefits:

- The function has the `smoothOrder` annotation defined, which allows the Modelica translator to differentiate your `flux` variable analytically .
  (With the annotations `smooth` and `smoothOrder` you can define up to which order the derivative is continuous)
- Instead of the algorithm section we can use a single equation section.
  (You should avoid algorithm sections to describe physical behavior, as it limits the Modelica translator in manipulating your equations to create a solvable system. With algorithm sections you force the code to be evaluated exactly how you have written it, which is against the principle of a-causal physical modeling)

Unfortunately, OpenModelica still has some trouble to simulate the new model with your simulation setup (trapezoidal rule, tolerance=1e-6). By reducing the tolerance to 1e-4 the simulation finishes, but still showing the warning

> Restart Kinsol: change linear solver to KINDense.

many many times. Maybe an OpenModelica expert can help on that.

Dymola by the way has no troubles with the new code, regardless of the selected solver.